# Обмен строк матрицы

Tags: c++, c++11

Если матрица хранится как `int** matrix`, то можно быстро обменять строки с помощью обмена указателей `std::swap(matrix[x], matrix[y]);`. Как быстро обменять строки у матрицы, хранящейся в виде `std::array<std::array<value_type, M>, N>`?

Comment: swap пробовали?

Answer (score 1):

Использовать стандартный `swap` - ведь каждая строка - это просто `std::array` (со столбцами так просто не получилось бы...)

Вот [так](https://ideone.com/odZHRL):

```
array<array<int, 5>, 5> a;
...
std::swap(a[1],a[3]);
```

Или

```
a[1].swap(a[3]);
```

Ну, или стандартный обмен:

```
array<int, 5> tmp;
tmp  = a[1];
a[1] = a[3];
a[3] = tmp;
```