# Обмен строк статической матрицы

Tags: c++, c, алгоритм, указатели, матрицы

Воспользовался материалами:
[ссылка 1](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/748599/%d0%9e%d0%b1%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%ba-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%86%d1%8b)
[ссылка 2](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/931800/%D0%9E%D0%B1%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%86%D1%8B)

К сожалению не смог интерпретировать это на свой случай.
Идея простая, есть двоичная матрица xyz:

XY Y1  Y2  ... Yn
X1 Z11 Z12 ... Z1n
X2 Z21 Z22 ... Z2n
.. ... ... ... ...
Xn Zn1 Zn2 ... Znn

Требуется отсортировать по строкам через указатели
Вот код:

```
    void sort_matrix(double mtr[10][10], int n, int m) {
    // sort by x
        for (int j = 1; j < n - 1; j++) {
            if (mtr[j][0] > mtr[j + 1][0]) {
                double *addr1 = &mtr[j];
                double *addr2 = &mtr[j + 1];
                double *temp = addr1;
                addr1 = addr2;
                addr2 = temp;
            } 
        }
}
```

Не работает сортировка ни по отдельности для строк или столбцов, ни вместе
Как этот код привести в порядок?

Comment: Для начала разберитесь в чём различие между *указателем на данные* и самими *данными*. У вас каким образом создаётся `mtr`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для начала - тут

```
double *addr1 = &mtr[j][0];
double *addr2 = &mtr[j + 1][0];
double *temp = addr1;
addr1 = addr2;
addr2 = temp;
```

вы просто меняете местами содержимое двух переменных - адреса элементов массива, но никак не сами элементы!

```
double temp = mtr[j][0];
mtr[j][0] = mtr[j+1][0]
mtr[j+1][0] = temp;
```

куда больше толку...

Дальше - а что вы хотите в конечном итоге? Допустим, вы отсортировали по строкам, но, сортируя по столбцам, вы же опять перемешаете строки.

Какова конечная цель?

Comment: Еще больше конкретизировал и упростил задачу, немного размыто, вы правы.  
Требуется обмен строк через указатели в двоичном статическом массиве

Comment: Ну, я вам ответил, куда смотреть...

Comment: У вас обмен значений, или я не прав?

Comment: Да, только вам менять нужно в цикле всю строку/столбец. Мне бы не хотелось писать готовый код, если вы напишете его сами - вы его запомните навсегда :) Но если не пойдет - ну что ж, обращайтесь... Да, как я понимаю, стандартный алгоритм `sort` использовать нельзя?